# Конфигурационный файл txt для js

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторый iframe с видео, который открывается на странице по таймауту. Можно ли сделать конфиг в формате .txt и управлять таймером и одним из видео?
Пример:

```
video_type=sequence/random. 
video_idle_time=600 
videoID=1;video_name=video1.mp4
videoID=2;video_name=video2.mp4
videoID=3;video_name=video3.mp4
videoID=4;video_name=video4.mp4
videoID=5;video_name=video5.mp4
```

Видео будут браться рандомно, закрывая весь контент и выглядеть должно быть так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно реализовать? Спасибо.

Comment: JS не работает с FS, а вот сервер может прочитать конфиг и передать на фронт.

Comment: @Other задача стоит сделать статику на html/css/js. С серверами не дружу, но раз есть задача, то придется видимо) Как это можно сделать, можете подсказать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Без языка, который имеет доступ к файловой системе, файл не прочитаешь. Если есть только он, то, пожалуй, можно только сохранить файл, потом ручками его передавать в `input[type=file]` и там JS может читать. Правда это муторно, сохраняйте конфиг в куках/хранилище, они созданы для хранения.

Comment: @Other можно, пожалуйста, поподробней? Опишу поподробней. Будет статичная сайт с 10 страницами, на каждой странице, если пользователь не проявляется активности - вешается почти на полный экран видео, закрывается по клику (а точнее, тачу. для тачскрин моников) мне нужно будет поднять локальный серв и там уже привязывать txt, как я понял. Как это можно связать? Как мне гуглить это дело?) Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: txt файл находится где? на сервере? грузите его ajax'ом в страницу и парсите.

Comment: @Igor клиент сказал, что не нужно использовать php и другие серверные языки. Можно ли как то через js? и как потом значение из txt передать в js?

Comment: еще раз: где находится txt файл? Чтобы загрузить статический текстовый файл ajax'ом с сервера в страницу никакого php не нужно.

Comment: @Igor txt файл будет загружен на сервер один раз и редактируя его (таймаут, файлы видео) будут изменяться и сами видео на странице. Например: было - videoID=1;video_name=video1.mp4, после редактирования videoID=1;video_name=video2.mp4

Comment: @Igor добавил к вопросу скрин

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  method:"GET",
  dataType:"text",
  url:"static.txt",
  success:function(data) {
    // parse string data here
  }
});
```

Я бы рассмотрел вариант с данными в файле в формате JSON. Тогда data - это уже js объект:

```
{
  "video_type":"sequence/random", 
  "video_idle_time":600,
  "videos":[ 
    {"ID":1,"name":"video1.mp4"},
    {"ID":2,"name":"video2.mp4"},
    {"ID":3,"name":"video3.mp4"}
  ]
}

$.ajax({
  method:"GET",
  dataType:"json",
  url:"static.txt",
  success:function(data) {
    console.log(data.video_idle_time);
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать